# sending message to a client using SocketServer in python

Tags: python, network-programming, socketserver

I'm building a TCP server using the SocketServer module in python.

As it seems to me, SocketServer.TCPServer functionality is destined to reply to a client that sent a request to the server but not for random communication between the server and the client. For example - Chat between the server and the client..

Is there any way to just send a message to some client registered to the server?

My code for now:

```
import SocketServer
import chathandler
import threading

PORT = 12345

def do_main():
    global httpd

    Handler = chathandler.ChatHandler

    httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

    print "Serving at port:", PORT
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target = do_main)
    server_thread.start()

    while True:
        print "Send message to the clients"
        s = raw_input(": ")
        # TODO: Send the message!
```

In this example i want to send the message to all the clients connected to the server.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please explain which functionality are you thinking to provide using this thing.

Comment: The basic use i can find for this is a chat between 2 or more clients and the server as a relaying station. When it gets message from one client it needs to pass it to all the other clients.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this is by using [HTTP persistent connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection).
As can be quoted from the article:

> HTTP persistent connection, also called HTTP keep-alive, or HTTP
>   connection reuse, is the idea of using a single TCP connection to send
>   and receive multiple HTTP requests/responses, as opposed to opening a
>   new connection for every single request/response pair.

**BaseHttpRequestHandler** class (which ChatHandler inherits from) has a member called "**protocol_version**" which as we can see in its documentation:

> This specifies the HTTP protocol version used in responses. If set to
>   'HTTP/1.1', the server will permit HTTP persistent connections;
>   however, your server must then include an accurate Content-Length
>   header (using send_header()) in all of its responses to clients. For
>   backwards compatibility, the setting defaults to 'HTTP/1.0'.

so, by assigning Handler.protocol_version = 'HTTP/1.1', the connection won't be closed immediately after processing one request, but will stay to process other requests as well. So the last thing i done, is to override TCPServer's **get_request** and **close_request** methods.

**get_request** is called to accept a connection.

**close_request** is called to close a connection.

In **get_request** i added a command after accepting the connection to add the connection to a list of all the current connections and in **close_request** i added a command to remove this connection from the same list.